# PySpark - Can aggregation operations be part of a pipeline?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pipeline

Can aggregation operations be part of a pipeline(Spark/PySpark)? An example of aggregation operations is to aggregate a dataframe to user id level and compute various statistics for each column such as min, max, mean, etc.

Comment: do you mean the spark ML pipeline?

Comment: Sure - there even is a SQL transformer - or you could create your own.